# How do I setup a subapplication on appharbor

Tags: web-config, appharbor, subapplication

I'm currently working on a website, discgolfauctions.com. As currently setup, it has two pieces, the main application (currently just a landing page) and a blog. The blog is run using BlogEngine.NET and lives in underneath the main application as a sub application. So, I can access the two like so:

Main site: `http://discgolfauctions.com`

Blog: `http://discgolfauctions.com/blog`

I'm working on moving my application to AppHarbor from my shared hosting provider but I'm running into a roadblock for which I am unable to find any information. How do I setup my application in the same fashion? Would I be able to do it using only a single AppHarbor application or would it require two? I know something similar could be achieved using sub domains and two applications but would like to keep the same URL structure for SEO purposes.